# difference between https ,ssl and pci dss compliance

Tags: ssl, https, pci-compliance

Hello anybody describe me. I am always confused . 
what is difference between **HTTPS**, **SSL** and **PCI compliance.**

how HTTPS work ??

how SSL work ??

how PCI work ??

Comment: This question is quite a bit too broad for this format. However, PCI has nothing to do with the other two items - it's just a set of standards for companies who store/use credit card information. It's not an actual protocol.

Comment: we need to implement PCI like SSL . and what difference between

Comment: What do you mean "implement PCL like SSL"? That doesn't even make sense, it's an apples-to-oranges comparison.

Comment: i am new for this topic . SSl Provide us secure data transmission than why we need PCI?

Comment: There's a lot more to PCI compliance than just secure data transmission. There's a lot more to data security than that too; you could exchange information in a perfectly secure way and store it in a completely insecure way. For example, do people who don't need it have easy physical access to your servers? Do you salt your passwords? Do you have properly-implemented firewalls? Do your servers have virus scan/anti-spyware software? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

SSL, which has since been replaced by [Transport Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (TLS), is basically a set of cryptography protocols to ensure private communication from a client endpoint (e.g. web browser) to a server. Apart from private communication, when properly implemented, it also includes mutual authentication of the client and server (i.e. the client verifies that it's communicating with the server it thinks it's communicating with and the server verifies that the client is really who they claim they are) and some kind of tamper resistance; these are to prevent [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and provide a partial defense against [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack).

HTTPS just means that you're using HTTP over TLS or SSL.

As I describe in my comments, PCI standards are very different than either SSL or HTTPS. PCI standards are exactly that - a standard for data security, not a specific network or cryptography protocol.

Here is a description of what PCI compliance means (from the [PCI Compliance Guide FAQ](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/)):

> The Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS) is a set of
>   security standards designed to ensure that ALL companies that accept,
>   process, store or transmit credit card information maintain a secure
>   environment.

It's very important to note that there's a lot more to PCI compliance (and to software security in general) than just secure data exchange. In fact, the FAQ I link to above addresses that specifically; in response to the question "Am I PCI compliant if I have an SSL certificate?" they say the following:

> No. SSL certificates do not secure a web server from malicious attacks
>   or intrusions. High assurance SSL certificates provide the first tier
>   of customer security and reassurance... but there are other steps to
>   achieve PCI compliance.

Some examples of other things you have to consider for data security:

- Do you store passwords and other sensitive data properly on your server (e.g. salting them, etc.)?
- Do you have adequate network security (e.g. firewalls) in place? (Note that, as described in the book I link to below, even then you shouldn't assume that merely having a firewall is a complete defense against security problems).
- Do you have adequate physical security in place? For example, how feasible would it be for someone to walk into your server room and gain access to the servers? Do you have to scan a badge to get in to the server room, and is access restricted to authorized employees?
- Do you run code with [least permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)?
- Has code been reviewed and tested for common security bugs like [buffer overruns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and [integer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)?

There's an excellent book out there called [24 Deadly Sins of Software Security](http://a.co/02t4YcK) that describes common security bugs.

Answer (score 1):

### **SSL**

**Definition:** SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) is a security protocol commonly used in circumstances like E-Comm, with Verisign etc to protect personally identifiable information during web transactions, as well as other sensitive data like credit card numbers and logins. SSL certificates generally need to be bought and installed on your web server.

More reading here: https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/

### HTTPS

**Definition:** HTTPS is HTTP + SSL certificate.

HTTPS (Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure) is the secure version of HTTP. The "S" implies that all data that is sent over the browser is encrypted.
**Example:** Google Searches

### **PCI**

**Definition:** PCI DSS Compliance Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard is the global data security standard for credit card payments. I agree that it doesn't make sense to "implement PCL like SSL". PCI compliance governs everything from the hardware (card reader or point of sale) to your payment gateway. It's much easier to go with a payment processor that is already PCI compliant, as adhering to standards independently is probably not worth your time. Square has a basic guide here: https://squareup.com/guides/pci-compliance